# How may I change legacy datatables columns order?

Tags: jquery, datatables

My issue is that I have to change columns order according to a request variable.
I've looked all over the internet nada !!
It's a legacy datatable.
Anyone knows please? May you kindly give some links ?

Comment: Check `ColReorder`

Comment: Change the order as a result of a query, or the actual order within the table itself? If its the later, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

Option aaSorting or asSorting

Maybe should access to that variable after initialisation after oSettings and use fnDraw() after change setting to re draw the table

Comment: Hi, I mean't columns order. I didn't say I want to sort them.
For example : default order ABCD. I want to modify the order as follows : DCAB. Thanks

Comment: @Sofiane I'd use the ColReorder plugin for this, it allows changing the column order after initialization. I haven't ever changed the column order programatically though. Legacy: https://legacy.datatables.net/extras/colreorder/, recent: https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/#Features

Comment: @Csaba Toth : sorry but this issue is already resolved since so long. Sorry but I left my previous work Soni can't provide solution.